# Post request cakephp

Tags: php, json, cakephp

I'm trying to send a post request that header is json and the response also is json. What i have tried so far. This always return a `status` code `400`. what i'm doing wrong?Thanks

```
 private function requestPOST($url,$data)
{
    App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
    App::uses('Json', 'Utility');
    $this->layout = 'default';
    $this->autoRender = true;
    $HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();

    $jsonData = json_encode($data);
    $request = array('header' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));

    debug($url);


    $response = $HttpSocket->post($url, $jsonData, $request);



    debug($response->code);

    //$this->render('index');

    $jsonString = json_decode($response['body'], true);

    debug($jsonString);

    return $jsonString;
}
```

Comment: You should really be using a view class to achieve this. Check out the documentation for [CakePHP 2](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) or [CakePHP 3](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have solved myself. I was doing twice `json_encode` of the $data.